# How to select query row number 2 where I set LIMIT 3

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask, how to select row value when I set LIMIT 3 
here my query :

```
SELECT
   COUNT(tbl_transaction.idimport_database) AS jumlah,
   product_name
FROM
  tbl_transaction
GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY jumlah DESC LIMIT 3
```

Result :
[image]

I want to showing row query number 2, I marked Yellow.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want the second row? Presumably you want the value for Ice lemon Tea? In which case, use a where clause.

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets, so you need some way of defining the second row (as opposed to the first) - which is (in part) why we have the concept of the PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach is to select only the second line:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(tbl_transaction.idimport_database) AS jumlah,
   product_name
FROM
  tbl_transaction
GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY jumlah DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset parameter in the limit clause to provide the offset.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(idimport_database) AS jumlah,
   product_name
FROM
  tbl_transaction
GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY jumlah DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

But as per your data, the above can return either of the first two rows as the value is same for both. You can provide another column in the ordering clause to specify exactly which row you'd like.